# cannot create editTexts at runtime

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to add three editText adjacent to each other when a user gives focus to a view.
Also I want that when the user taps the first editText, a new set of 3 editTexts are created just below the existing ones.

This code is returning an error(nullPointerException)

```
 @Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){

    // 5 is the id of the view
    case 5:

        main=new RelativeLayout(this);
        mainParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
        main.setLayoutParams(mainParams);

        //mainLayout is a LinearLayout


        items[no]=new EditText(this);
        rates[no]=new EditText(this);
        quants[no]=new EditText(this);

        items[no].setHint("Enter item name");
        rates[no].setHint("Rate");
        quants[no].setHint("Quantity");

        items[no].setId(id++);
        rates[no].setId(id++);
        quants[no].setId(id++);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams etParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        etParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        rParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT);


        items[no].setLayoutParams(etParams);
        rates[no].setLayoutParams(rParams);
        quants[no].setLayoutParams(rParams);
        mainLayout.addView(main);
        no++;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
// 5 is the id of the view
    case 5:

        main=new RelativeLayout(this);
        mainParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
        main.setLayoutParams(mainParams);

        //mainLayout is a LinearLayout


        items[no]=new EditText(this);
        rates[no]=new EditText(this);
        quants[no]=new EditText(this);



        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams etParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        etParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        rParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT);


        items[no].setLayoutParams(etParams);
        rates[no].setLayoutParams(rParams);
        quants[no].setLayoutParams(rParams);
        mainLayout.addView(main);

 items[no].setHint("Enter item name");
        rates[no].setHint("Rate");
        quants[no].setHint("Quantity");

        items[no].setId(id++);
        rates[no].setId(id++);
        quants[no].setId(id++);
        no++;

    }
```

Comment: yeah i have tried this before shifting (mainLayout.addView(main);) but it does not matter.  It returns the same error